# Click one of contact in contact list in whatsapp web (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, web

I try to use JavaScript to perform a click action to click a contact form contact list in order to open a chat in Whatsapp Web.

I use normal click action to click but not working, like

```
var div = document.querySelector('.infinite-list-item')[0];
div.click();
```

And i know whatsapp web is made by react js, ant special to perform a click?

I even use jQuery click() function but still not working, what should I use?

Comment: `querySelector()` returns first matching element...there is no `querySelector()[0]`. Beyond that this question is far too broad. Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: any luck yet? tried using jQuery and clicking the element and all its parent - no luck either. I am not sure, if this is about the devs having used reactJS or  because they protected it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to emulate click on a contact in WhatsApp web from browser JS console?

Answer (score 1):

---

You're using `document.querySelector()` and then trying to access it as if it was a data structure.

`document.querySelector()` will return only one DOM element. You should try using `document.querySelectorAll()[0]` if you want to put all the contacts in a structure.

Solution:

```
    var itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.infinite-list-item');
    itemList[0].click();
```

Also, this would work as an alternative solution ( though using querySelector instead of querySelectorAll to target a class name that is used more than once is not at all recommended ):

```
    var div = document.querySelector('.infinite-list-item');
    div.click();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried all your solution tried all but still not work. I tried both of them in the console and just return undefined. The chat is not opened.

Comment: Use the mousedown event. Chat is opened on with mousedown.

function simulateMouseEvents(element, eventName) {
    var mouseEvent= document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    mouseEvent.initEvent (eventName, true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent (mouseEvent);
}

simulateMouseEvents('element to click', "mousedown")

Answer (score 0):

```
         document.queryselectorAll("div span").forEach((/*YourElement*/, index) =>{
             setTimeout(()=>{
                  
                  /*here should go a validation so that it only runs on the 
                  contacts you want, but i don't write it because that's not the 
                   main idea*/

                 //¡¡¡¡the important part is this!!!!!

                 function simulateMouseEvents (elemento, eventName) {
                     var mouseEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
                     mouseEvent.initEvent (eventName, true, true);
                     /*YourElement*/.dispatchEvent (mouseEvent);
                 }
                 simulateMouseEvents ('enlace', "mousedown");

             },index*20)
         }
```

/*this code snippet solved my problem in a personal project ... I am enclosing  image of the project(unfinished so it may have bugs) in case it helps you understand better*/

[Image of the proyect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR6ld.png)